# pexpect regex not working

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

I am having a script which uses pexpect to telnet to a switch and copy its running config to a tftp server. If I give the hostname, then the script works fine but while using regex in pexect, timeout  occurs. The code is as follows:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('telnet ' +ip)
child.expect ('Login: ')
child.sendline (username)
child.expect ('Password: ')
child.sendline (password)
child.sendline ('enable')
child.expect('Password: ')
child.sendline(password)
child.expect('.*\-.*#')
child.sendline ('copy running-config tftp://10.0.37.111/'+filename+'.txt')
time.sleep(5)
```

I am giving the above regex as the hostname for my current switch is Force10-60. Thanks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - What if the switch hostname is not known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
child.expect(r'.+\-.+#')
```

You can try this by providing `raw string` .

Or use

```
child.expect('#')
```

To match any hostname

Comment: Thanks. It works!!But can you help if there is any way to get the hostname of the switch to get the above filename from the switch itself. Thanks.

Comment: @deep after expect do `print child.before`.There u will have the hostname

Answer (score 5):

I know this question already has accepted answer but I would like to add an explanation on how to handle matched regular expression.

So, my problem was that I needed to get a string that appeared between two specific strings.
This is how I solved my problem:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn(...)
child.sendline(...)
child.expect(r'firstString(.*?)secondString')

regex_obj = child.match
print(regex_obj.group(1).decode('utf-8'))
```

Hope this would help someone!